# Overlapping Buttons due to Cell Reuse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having some trouble with the dequeue reusable cell function in my `UITableView`. The tableview has a couple of cells, each of which contains a button.

When I scroll, the cell is recreated, and new buttons begin to overlap old buttons (until I have a bunch of the same buttons in the same cell). I've heard that your supposed to use the `removeFromSuperview` function to fix this, but i'm not really sure how to do it.

Here is a picture of my app:

[image]

And here is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (where the problem is occurring)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:   IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)


    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Sample Item"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let actionButton = YSSegmentedControl(
        frame: CGRect.zero,
        titles: [
            "No",
            "Yes"
        ])
```

Comment: You haven't posted the whole function for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  You need to post more of that function.  In particular, the bits where you add the label and button/segmented control to the cell.  I suspect that you are adding these items every time you dequeue the cell, without ever removing them.  Does your image really illustrate the problem at all?  I can't see any overlapping buttons in your image.

Comment: not recommended at all to create or remove views in `cellForRowAt indexPath.`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing multiple buttons appear is because the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method is called every time a new table cell is needed. Since you are likely creating the button in that method body, it is getting recreated every time the cell is reused and you'll see them stack on top like that. The correct way to use dequeueReusableCell: with custom elements is to create a subclass of a UITableViewCell and set that as the class of your table cell in your storyboard. Then when you call dequeueReusableCell: you'll get a copy of your subclass that will contain all of your custom code. You will need to do a type conversion to get access to any of that custom code like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:   IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
  if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as? MyCustomCellClass {
    cell.nameLabel.text = "Sample item"
  }

  // This return path should never get hit and is here only as a typecast failure fallback
  return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath);
}
```

Your custom cell subclass would then look something like this:

```
class MyCustomCellClass: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var actionButton: UIButton!

  @IBAction func actionButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //Do something when this action button is pressed
  }
}
```

Comment: In other words, *never, ever* add or remove subviews in `cellForRowAt`. Instead, add them elsewhere (*cough* storyboard *cough*), and change their *properties* in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: I would, but I don't use storyboards. I tried using a custom cell class but it's significantly more difficult.

Comment: @NicholasTiwari if my memory serves me correctly (it's been a while) but you should be able to just use a regular nib file if you don't want to use a full storyboard. Otherwise, custom cell class is the way to go. If you're struggling with that, post a question so we can help.

Comment: Will do, I kind of cobbled it together without the custom cell class and it worked so I had trouble ditching that and starting over. The custom cell method would definitely be the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new label/button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but you need to make sure there is no existing label/button before you create and add new ones. One way to do it is to set a tag to the label/button, and before you generate new label/button, check if the view with the tag is already in the cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    if let label = cell.viewWithTag(111) as? UILabel
    {
        label.text = "Second Labels"
    }
    else{
        let label = UILabel()
        label.tag = 111
        label.text = "First Labels"
        cell.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:10, width: 100, height:30)
    }

    return cell
}
```